# Managed object data one-to-many write data

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a data model in my small application with two small tables: Test and subTest, where Test can have many subTests.

Into Test table we can add as many as we want items and for each item in Test table there is a bunch of items in subTest table.

I can easily request a data from the subTest table associated with Test1, Test2 etc by using CoreData predicates and then using valueForKeyPath. However, I have the problem with saving data into the subTest table. I cannot managed, how to write data in a way, that later on I can fetch this data by passing the test name (e.g. Test1) and then using valueForKeyPath.

Here is an example to clarify what I did mean.

In table Test is a Test1 associated with the the bunch of subtests(st1, st2). Now the subtest st3 must be added to the subTest table. Later we want to get bunch of subtests associated with Test1:

```
Test test = call here the method which returns NSManagedObject;
NSMutableSet setOfSubTests = [test valueForKeyPath testTosubtests.toTest]; /* Returns st1 st2 and st3 */
```

Is it only about to write data to the subTest table using old school indexes? (Test1 has index 1 and in subTest table all subtests associated with it have Test1 index)? Is the right thing to do with a CoreData in iOS? Can I apply the same principles as with common SQL DB?

All those things(CoreData and NSManagedObject) are quite new to me. And I want to understand them better.

Comment: Really no idea what you're asking here, can you show actual code samples?

Comment: I am only asking about best practices on how to store data in the file with the NSManagedObjectContext. Can I apply same principles  as in the cases with SQL DB (using indecies between parent and child tables) if the file I am storing data to is an SQLite?
I just do not know how else it can be explained, because the whole concept of the coredata is a new for me.

Comment: Don't think of it as SQL, think of instances and relationships

Comment: Forget SQL and consider reading the [manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop thinking about core data as database tables.  Core data was designed to manage collections of related objects.  It's underlying implementation may be an SQL database, or a flat binary file, or some custom store implementation.  **Do not** think of it as a database with tables and such.

Now, as for your example...

> I have a data model in my small application with two small tables:
>   Test and subTest, where Test can have many subTests.

You would have a Test entity, and a Subtest entity.  The Test entity would have a to-many relationship to Subtest, since one test can "hold" many Subtest entities.

The Subtest entity would have a to-one relationship to Test since a Subtest can only belong to one Test.

I understand things better in code, so the model may look like this when described in code.

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel*)modelForTestsAndSubtests {
    NSEntityDescription *testEntity = [[NSEntityDescription alloc] init];
    testEntity.name = @"Test";
    NSAttributeDescription *testName = [[NSAttributeDescription alloc] init];
    testName.name = @"name";
    testName.attributeType = NSStringAttributeType;

    NSEntityDescription *subtestEntity = [[NSEntityDescription alloc] init];
    subtestEntity.name = @"Subtest";
    NSAttributeDescription *subtestName = [[NSAttributeDescription alloc] init];
    subtestName.name = @"name";
    subtestName.attributeType = NSStringAttributeType;

    // A Test can have many Subtest objects in its relationship
    NSRelationshipDescription *testToSubtests = [[NSRelationshipDescription alloc] init];
    testToSubtests.optional = YES;
    testToSubtests.name = @"subtests";
    testToSubtests.destinationEntity = subtestEntity;
    testToSubtests.deleteRule = NSCascadeDeleteRule;
    testToSubtests.minCount = testToSubtests.maxCount = 0;
    testToSubtests.ordered = NO;

    // A Subtest can (and must) reference exactly one Test
    NSRelationshipDescription *subtestToTest = [[NSRelationshipDescription alloc] init];
    subtestToTest.optional = NO;
    subtestToTest.name = @"test";
    subtestToTest.destinationEntity = testEntity;
    subtestToTest.inverseRelationship = testToSubtests;
    subtestToTest.deleteRule = NSNullifyDeleteRule;
    subtestToTest.minCount = subtestToTest.maxCount = 1;

    testToSubtests.inverseRelationship = subtestToTest;

    testEntity.properties = @[testName, testToSubtests];
    subtestEntity.properties = @[subtestName, subtestToTest];

    NSManagedObjectModel *model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] init];
    model.entities = @[testEntity, subtestEntity];
    return model;
}
```

> However, I have the problem with saving data into the subTest table.

Again, don't think of it as saving data into a table.  Think of it as "I'm going to add subtest "st1" to "Test1"

You would do that like this...

```
NSManagedObject *subtest = [NSEntityDescription
    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Subtest"
             inManagedObjectContext:test.managedObjectContext];
[subtest setValue:test forKey:@"test"];
```

Note that when you assign the to-one relationship from the Subtest entity to the Test entity, core data will automatically setup the inverse relationship, so you don't have to add the subtest to the to-many relationship in the Test entity.

Now, let's say you insert 10 subtests (this is just for testing)...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    NSManagedObject *subtest = [NSEntityDescription
        insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Subtest"
                 inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    [subtest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"st%02d", i] forKey:@"name"];
    [subtest setValue:test forKey:@"test"];
}
[moc save:&error]; // Handle failure and error appropriately...
```

> I cannot managed, how to write data in a way, that later on I can
>   fetch this data by passing the test name (e.g. Test1) and then using
>   valueForKeyPath.

So, if you want to get the test with name "Test1" you could write something like this...

```
- (NSManagedObject*)existingTestWithName:(NSString*)name
                                   inMOC:(NSManagedObjectContext*)moc
                                   error:(NSError**)error {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Test"];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", name];
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1;

    NSManagedObject *result = nil;
    NSArray *fetched = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:error];
    if (fetched) {
        if (error) *error = nil;
        result = [fetched firstObject];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then, you could grab 'Test1' like so...

```
NSManagedObject *test = [self existingTestWithName:@"Test1" inMOC:moc error:&error];
if (test) {
    // Do something with the Test entity that has name "Test1"
}
```

And then, once you have the test object, you can get access to all the Subtest objects for this test instance via its "subtests" relationship.

```
NSSet *subtests = [test valueForKey:@"subtests"];
```

Thus, you can find a specific subtest by simply searching the collection...

```
- (NSManagedObject*)findExistingSubtestWithName:(NSString*)name
                                        forTest:(NSManagedObject*)test {
    // This is "simple" but could yield less than optimal performance
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", name];
    NSSet *subtests = [test valueForKey:@"subtests"];
    return [[subtests filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate] anyObject];
}
```

However, this causes all subtests to be loaded into memory to perform an iterative search.  Tis is fine if the objects are relatively small, and there are a small number of them.

Or, you can actually perform a fetch...

```
- (NSManagedObject*)fetchExistingSubtestWithName:(NSString*)name
                                         forTest:(NSManagedObject*)test
                                           error:(NSError**)error {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Subtest"];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate
        predicateWithFormat:@"test = %@ AND name = %@", test, name];
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1;

    NSManagedObject *result = nil;
    NSArray *fetched = [test.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                error:error];
    if (fetched) {
        if (error) *error = nil;
        result = [fetched firstObject];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Since you seem to be familiar with SQL, here is the SQL that core data generates for the fetch above.

```
SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZTEST
FROM ZSUBTEST t0 JOIN ZTEST t1 ON t0.ZTEST = t1.Z_PK
WHERE ( t0.ZNAME = ? AND  t1.ZNAME = ?)  LIMIT 1
```

However, that is just to show you how the fetch happens.  You should still think of everything as interconnected objects, and don't worry about the implementation of the store being SQL until you need to be concerned about performance issues.

---

### Note

You can generate subclass code in Xcode and third party tools like [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator) that can greatly enhance your experience using managed objects.  However, it's still good to know how it all works.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful answer. It seems, I have to read one more time the manual. The bad thing is, however, Apple, removed very good old manuals about CoreData with code samples. Instead of them there is only short description and some diagrams (well, it was not enough for me during the learning process). Here was a very good manual: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOM.html

Comment: @user1415536 - Pull up the documentation in Xcode, and you will see a lot of detailed documents, including a bunch of programming guides, reference documentation for all classes, WWDC videos, and even a good amount of sample code.